# How to test unseen sentences for a new classifier in scikit learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp

I have created a model using this dataset and I would like to insert some sentences to see how they would be classified. How can I do that?

Here is the code that makes the model:

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn import metrics

cats = ['sci.space','rec.autos']
newsgroups_train = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='train',
                   remove=('headers', 'footers', 'quotes'), categories = cats)
newsgroups_test = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='test',
                   remove=('headers', 'footers', 'quotes'), categories = cats)

vectors_test = vectorizer.transform(newsgroups_test.data)
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
vectors = vectorizer.fit_transform(newsgroups_train.data)
clf = MultinomialNB(alpha=.01)
clf.fit(vectors, newsgroups_train.target)
vectors_test = vectorizer.transform(newsgroups_test.data)
pred = clf.predict(vectors_test)
metrics.f1_score(newsgroups_test.target, pred, average='macro')
```

the accuracy it returns is: `0.97` which shows that there is overfitting.

As mentioned, I would like to test how the classification of unseen data would occur. How can I proceed?

Example I tried:

```
texts = ["The space shuttle is made in 2018", 
         "The exhaust is noisy.",
         "the windows are transparent."]
text_features = tfidf.transform(texts)
predictions = model.predict(text_features)
for text, predicted in zip(texts, predictions):
  print('"{}"'.format(text))
  print("  - Predicted as: '{}'".format(id_to_category[predicted]))
  print("")
 #this does not work as it is
```

It should classify each sentence to one of the two (sci.space, rec.autos) categories.

Furthermore, any other suggestions you may have about the whole code are welcome. I want to learn these processes very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you are using variable names which are different from the ones that you defined above.

In your code that makes the model:
- your model is called clf, so when you use it afterwards you should write clf.predict (not model.predict)
- your TfidfVectorizer is called vectorizer, so when you use it afterwards use the same variable name (not a new one like tfidf)

Your example becomes:

```
texts = ["The space shuttle is made in 2018", 
     "The exhaust is noisy.",
     "the windows are transparent."]
text_features = vectorizer.transform(texts)
predictions = clf.predict(text_features)
for text, predicted in zip(texts, predictions):
   print('"{}"'.format(text))
   print("  - Predicted as: '{}'".format(predicted))
   print("")
```

which runs ok:

"The space shuttle is made in 2018"
  - Predicted as: '1'

"The exhaust is noisy."
  - Predicted as: '0'

"the windows are transparent."
  - Predicted as: '1'

Also in your traning code, make sure these 3 lines are in the right order:

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
vectors = vectorizer.fit_transform(newsgroups_train.data)
vectors_test = vectorizer.transform(newsgroups_test.data)
```

Comment: How can it use the actual names of the categories in the result? Instead of "Predicted as '1'" how can it say: "Predicted  as rec.autos"?

Comment: you can create a python dictionary (for ex. called id_to_category in your example above).